# Why doesn't DNS prefetching occur at the same time for every link?

Tags: javascript, css, web, dns, prefetch

I'm just trying to get a basic handle on how things are loaded on web pages. I've been prefetching DNS through the link tag in the head. I don't quite understand why some DNS lookups happen at different times than others. Since all links are listed one right after the other in the head, shouldn't they all work at the same time? Or at least one right after the other?

I would include an image, but I am not reputable enough yet :(

Comment: DNS resolutions can be cached on your computer, so that not always a request to a ARPA server is needed to resolve a DNS lookup.

Comment: In addition to the above, all requests are put into a request queue and are handled one by one as capacity to handle them exists…

Comment: @deceze Ahh I see, so even though they are listed in the head tag, they still pick and choose the best time to perform the DNS lookup for each link?